# Perl vCard.pm how do I compute inputs?

Tags: perl

The documentation for [vCard](https://metacpan.org/pod/vCard) shows it wants:

```
 addresses()
    Accepts/returns an arrayref that looks like:

      [
        { type => ['work'], street => 'Main St', preferred => 0 },
        { type      => ['home'], 
          pobox     => 1234,
          extended  => 'asdf',
          street    => 'Army St',
          city      => 'Desert Base',
          region    => '',
          post_code => '',
          country   => 'USA',
          preferred => 1,
        },
      ]
```

I must generate this call from a CSV file. I can extract the data, but cannot figure out how to pass it to `$vcard->addresses`.

This fails:

```
    if (keys %addrwork > 0 )
{
  $addrwork{'type'} = ['work'];
  push @arraytmp, %addrwork;
}
  # did we get any part of a home or work address?
  if ( $#arraytmp >= 0 ) {
$vcard->addresses( @arraytmp  );
```

Fails with:

```
Can't use string ("type") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use at /usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1/vCard.pm line 254, <FILE> line 2.
```

Answer (score 4):

> Accepts/returns an ***arrayref*** that looks like:

You're passing an array, not an arrayref. Fix it:

```
$vcard->addresses( \@arraytmp  );
```